# File not found trying to get all versions of a file from OneDrive using get-PnPFile

Tags: powershell, version, onedrive

I'm looking to write a PowerShell script to download of all versions from a single OneDrive file, but I can't get a valid URL for Get-PnPFile to accept.

```
$ctx= Get-PnPContext
$item = Get-PnPFile -Url [url] -AsListItem
$file = $item.file
$ctx.Load($file)
$fileVersions = $file.Versions
$ctx.Load($fileVersions)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach ($version in $fileVersions) {
       Get-PnPFile -Url $version.Url -Path z:\tmp -FileName ($file.Name + " " + $version.VersionLabel + ".json") -AsFile
    }
}
```

[Powershell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps) suggests you can use a site-relative Url for the -Url
the `$version.Url` has the format _vti_history/2662400/Documents/[filename]

adding `/personal/[email_address]/`... doesn't resolve the 'File Not Found' error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Get-PnPFile is not able to download the file from _vti_history. You need to use the CSOM functionality $version.OpenBinaryStream().

For SharePoint Online I'm using following code:

```
Get-PnPFile -Url $item.ServerRelativeUrl -Path $destinationFolderPath -AsFile -Force # Latest version
$ctx= Get-PnPContext
$ctx.Load($item.Versions)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach ($version in $item.Versions)
{
    $versionValue = $version.VersionLabel
    $str = $version.OpenBinaryStream()
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $filename =  (Split-Path $item.ServerRelativeUrl -Leaf) + "." + $versionValue
    $filepath = Join-Path $destinationFolderPath $filename
    $fs = New-Object IO.FileStream $filepath ,'Append','Write','Read'
    $str.Value.CopyTo($fs) # Older version
    $fs.Close()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.